# Define symbol to linked Swift framework

Tags: swift, xcode, symbols, compiler-flags

While writing iOS apps in Xcode, we may need to break down the project into smaller modules/frameworks that build independently, but within the same Xcode workspace.

Now, we have multiple targets, like QA, Staging and Prod, which have defined symbols, like `QATarget`, and `StagingTarget` to enable us to conditionally compile the code in the main target.

However, I am not aware of a good approach to pass those symbols down to the linked frameworks? I understand that we need to add a compiler flag to define those symbols, but is there a way to automatically inherit those flags in the sub-projects without dealing with build configuration ugliness (target based instead)?